# application crashed in rapidjson while coping json data?

Tags: reset, rapidjson

```
StringBuffer buffer;
    Writer<StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
    if (root.Accept(writer));
        return buffer.GetString();
    return std::string();
```

what i am doing wrong at line no. 3(`root.Accept(writer)). Application is getting crashed sometimes please suggest some solution

i tried multiple iteration. Crash is not always but sometimes